# keras backend conv2d error

Tags: python, keras, convolution

I am trying to use the `keras.backend.conv2d` function with my own kernel and I am getting the following error.

```
img = data[0,:,0]
img = img.reshape(240, 320)

kernelX = np.array([[-1, 1], 
                    [-1, 1]])

img = K.constant(img)
kernelX = K.constant(kernelX)

I_x = K.conv2d(img, kernelX)
```

> ValueError: number of input channels does not match corresponding
>   dimension of filter, 320 != 2

Could somebody please push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't specify which backend you use, the error is raised due to your reshaping operations. In this case, keras interprets the last element of the shape as the number of channels. That means, it supposes your image has 240 pixels with 320 channels and your kernel has two channels. For a convolution, these have to be the same size, though.

Therefore, you should create your image and kernels in a way, so that your image is of shape (240, 320, 1) and your kernel of shape (2, 2, 1).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I expanded the dimensions of both to (2, 2, 1) and (240, 320, 1) and tried it. Now the error says "number of input channels does not match corresponding dimension of filter, 1 != 2". I have double checked and tripled checked the dimensions of the image and kernel.

(I'm using Tensorflow backend btw).

Comment: From the documentation [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d): `Given an input tensor of shape [batch, in_height, in_width, in_channels] and a filter / kernel tensor of shape [filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels], this op performs the following: ...`. You might try to adjust your tensors accordingly and report the results.